# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'model_id' and 'model_id' is missing from visible fields

Tags: django-rest-framework

Something strange happened: I was defining an endpoint and initially two fields were visible in the API form: `model_id` and `payload`, as given in the model definition:

```py
### models.py:
class CarModel(models.Model):
    model_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_id


class Calculator(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payload = models.TextField()

    def model_id(self):
       return self.model.model_id

    def __str__(self):
       return f"Calculations for {self.model.name}"


### serializers.py:
class CalculatorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
       model = Calculator
       fields = ['model_id', 'payload']

    def get_model_id(self, obj):
       return obj.model_id()


### views.py:
class CalculatorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CalculatorSerializer
    queryset = Calculator.objects.all()      

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return Response(f"{serializer.data.upper()}", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

So, both fields were visible, but POST requests ended in the `AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'model_id'`. Trying to fix that, I eventually and accidentally removed `model_id` from view - it doesn't display in DRF's forms. And the `AttributeError` still persists.

What is wrong with this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out that defining `fields` in this manner:

```py
fields = '__all__'
```

makes also the `model_id` visible. Still, no idea why explicit insert doesn't work.

In case of the other issue, the `AttributeError`, I had to pull the value out of an OrderedDict. Modified method looks like this:

```py
def get_model_id(self, obj):
    return obj["model"].model_id
```

Beside that, I found one more error inside `views.py`'s `create` method: `serializer.data` won't implement `upper()` method; some key, in my case `serializer.data['payload']`, has to be referenced, so for example:

```py
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    res = {
            "payload": f"{serializer.data['payload'].upper()}"
    }

    return Response(res, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```